# Should we prefer plural in tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Earlier today I tried to tag a question "nouns", and the system wouldn't let me, saying that the tag [noun](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noun) already existed.

Just a minute ago, I wanted to tag another question "adjectives", same problem: [adjective](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adjective) already exists.

I am used to the plural form from other SE sites — ELU, GLU, and Linguistics. Their corresponding meta threads are:

- ELU: [Should we prefer singular or plural in tags?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/should-we-prefer-singular-or-plural-in-tags)
- GLU: [Should tags be pluralised?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/should-tags-be-pluralised)
- Linguistics: [2 questions about tags](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/2-questions-about-tags/)

I propose that we prefer the plural form on ELL as well. (The singular forms would still exist as automatically remapping synonyms.)

I did see the general discussion [good names for tags](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/good-names-for-tags), which (by virtue of it being general) has some overlap with this one, but I think this issue here is rather tiny and can be singled out and dealt with swiftly.

Answer (score 11):

I strongly agree with you, I feel this will help people that come from other SE sites to understand better. Thank you for making a point out of this, as many might have just found it unimportant.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not so important whether singular or plural is used, but that the form chosen be used consistently, and that the "other" form be accepted as a synonym.  Since plural seems to be the more common form used on other sites, then that is probably a better choice.