# Duplicate tags [adjective] and [adjectives]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I just noticed from [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24722/my-vs-mine-adjectives-vs-possesives) that we have both [adjective] and [adjectives].

This is strange because [this question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68/should-we-prefer-plural-in-tags) hints that [adjectives] can't have been created because of the prior existence of [adjective].

Anyway, I think they should be merged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge complete!

(This has to be the shortest meta answer ever. Thanks for pointing this out!)