# Singular tags to pluralize

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Per *[Should we prefer plural in tags?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68)*, for consistency with EL&U and other StackExchange sites, I believe the consensus was to use plural tag names for countables. In practice, we have something of a mishmash of singular and plural forms, particularly for terminology related to punctuation, sentence components, word forms, and parts of speech. In fact, we have both [part-of-speech](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/part-of-speech) (21 questions) and [parts-of-speech](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parts-of-speech) (6).

I propose we make [parts-of-speech](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parts-of-speech) the canonical tag, and that we pluralize the following:

- [complement](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complement)
- [constituent](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constituent)
- [false-friend](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/false-friend)
- [lexeme](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lexeme)
- [silent-letter](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/silent-letter)
- [time-construct](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-construct)
- [word-form](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-form)

For the others, I ask only that we choose a consistently singular or plural form.

#### Parts of speech

**Currently singular**

- [definite-article](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definite-article)
- [determiner](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/determiner)
- [indefinite-article](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indefinite-article)
- [relative-adverb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relative-adverb)
- [verb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb)

**Currently plural**

- [adverbial-particles](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverbial-particles)
- [articles](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles)
- [adjectives](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adjectives)
- [adverbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverbs)
- [auxiliary-verbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auxiliary-verbs)
- [collective-nouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collective-nouns)
- [conjunctions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjunctions)
- [correlative-conjunctions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correlative-conjunctions)
- [countable-nouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/countable-nouns)
- [irregular-verbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irregular-verbs)
- [modal-verbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modal-verbs)
- [nouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nouns)
- [personal-pronouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-pronouns)
- [phrasal-verbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrasal-verbs)
- [prepositions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prepositions)
- [pronouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronouns)
- [proper-nouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proper-nouns)
- [quantifiers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantifiers)
- [reflexive-pronouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reflexive-pronouns)
- [relative-pronouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relative-pronouns)
- [stative-verbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stative-verbs)
- [transitive-verbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transitive-verbs)
- [uncountable-nouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uncountable-nouns)

#### Verb forms

**Currently singular**

- [gerund](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gerund)
- [infinitive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinitive)
- [past-participle](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/past-participle)
- [present-participle](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/present-participle)

**Currently plural**

- [participles](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/participles)

#### Phrases and clauses

**Currently singular**

- [adverbial-phrase](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverbial-phrase)
- [infinitive-phrase](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinitive-phrase)
- [participial-clause](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/participial-clause)
- [phrase](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase)
- [prepositional-phrase](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prepositional-phrase)

**Currently plural**

- [absolute-clauses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/absolute-clauses)
- [clauses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clauses)
- [free-relative-clauses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-relative-clauses)
- [noun-phrases](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noun-phrases)
- [relative-clauses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relative-clauses)
- [restrictive-clauses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restrictive-clauses)
- [subordinate-clauses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subordinate-clauses)

#### Punctuation marks

**Currently singular**

- [hyphen](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyphen)
- [parenthesis](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parenthesis) (yes, I checked, they're about [parentheses](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/parentheses.htm), not [parenthesis](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/figures/P/parenthesis.htm), unlike the better-curated [ellipsis](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ellipsis))

**Currently plural**

- [colons](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colons)
- [commas](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commas)
- [periods](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/periods)
- [quotation-marks](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotation-marks)
- [semicolons](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semicolons)

#### Other

- [subject](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subject) and [predicate](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/predicate) but [objects](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objects)

Comment: Isn't "the" the only definite article in English? I'd say that one should remain singular while the 'indefinite-article' tag gets pluralized.

Comment: There's also only one indefinite article.  And yet, you can have multiple definite articles or indefinite articles in a given sentence, so the plural makes sense.